# How to sync data using google drive? Upload and download to drive works but I want to implement auto syncing

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-api, syn

I use drive api in my note app and sqlite database. The user can upload database.db file to drive and download it whenever they want, but here I want the app be able to sync data automatically whenever the user makes an update, add or delete a note, they should see the changes in all devices with the same account. My question is, how to sync data among devices that has the same google account in real time?

Comment: So you want to sync like the Android app of [Google Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1)? Do you use another program in Android to open the file?

Comment: I have device A with google account and I write a note, I want to have the same note to be synced on device B automatically that it has the same google Account on it.

Comment: You can do that with the Google Drive app. The app is available for [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google-drive/id507874739), [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs), [Windows and Mac](https://www.google.com/drive/download/). You need to install it to all your devices, and it will do exactly what you are discribing.

Comment: I think you didn't got what I meant. I have created a note app to write notes and I used sqlite database to store the notes. There are options to upload and download database to google drive whenever the user wants to backup or restore data, which is works pretty well. There are some users who use more than one device, may a phone and tablet. I need a way to synchronize notes in real time between or among devices that has the same account on them. I can make backup and restore operations to work automatically in the background, but this way has same drawbacks. I want only changes to synchroniz